# Laravel job middleware WithoutOverlapping - must not be accessed before initialization (php)

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Laravel 8 with PHP 7.4 and trying to implement a job that has the middleware of "WithoutOverlapping".

The job is dispatched onto a queue with the argument of "1", when the job is executed on the queue I receive the following error:

```
$hotelID must not be accessed before initialization
```

It seems that the __construct method is not being called before the middleware, how would I pass a key to the class constructor of WithoutOverlapping?

```php
class DeleteHotel implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels, HotelContentCache;

    private int $hotelID;

    public function __construct(int $hotelID)
    {
        $this->hotelID = $hotelID;
    }

    public function middleware(): array
    {
        return [(new WithoutOverlapping($this->hotelID))->releaseAfter(10)];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change

```
private int $hotelID;
```

to

```
protected int $hotelID;
```

and it will work.